# Guidance on automatic assumption equation

Tags: java

In this code I am trying to make it so that the int "Small" is assumed automatically after typing in the integer "Large."  The equation I have set for it is: small + large has to be =< 8, so when they type in 5 for "Large", then "Small" will output 3.  The code does compile successfully, but the output automatically, no matter what number I type in says, "the number of dogs has exceeded the facility limit."  Is something wrong with my equation?  I don't know what I am doing wrong.

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BarkingLot {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 20;
    int y = 25;
    int Large = 0;
    int Small = (8 - Large);
    int quit = 0;

    while (quit == 0){
     System.out.println("Enter number of large dogs: ");
    Large = Scanner.nextInt();

    int Revenue = ((Small * x) + (Large * y));
    int Food = ((Small + Large) * (2));
    int Facility = 30;
    int Expenses = (Food + Facility);
    int Difference = (Revenue - Expenses);

    if ((Small + Large) <= 8) {
      System.out.println("Revenue is " + ((Small * x) + (Large * y)));
      System.out.println("Expenses = " + (Food + Facility));
      System.out.println("Difference = " + (Revenue - Expenses));

    } else
      System.out.println("The number of dogs has exceeded the facility limit.");
  }
}
}
```

Comment: how small will be larger than the large?

Comment: I fixed it with the person's code underneath.  But it blocked it from using my else statement.  Do you know why?

Comment: I read your question but did not get what you are trying to solve? you may need to explain your logic or what you try to achieve please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you were initializing Small to early so it remained 8 all the way to the if statement where you check if Small + Large is less than or equal to 8.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BarkingLot {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = 20;
    int y = 25;
    int Large = 0;
    int Small;
    int quit = 0;

    while (quit == 0){
     System.out.println("Enter number of large dogs: ");
    Large = Scanner.nextInt();
    // need to initialize Small here.
    Small = (8 - Large);

    int Revenue = ((Small * x) + (Large * y));
    int Food = ((Small + Large) * (2));
    int Facility = 30;
    int Expenses = (Food + Facility);
    int Difference = (Revenue - Expenses);

    if ((Small + Large) <= 8) {
      System.out.println("Revenue is " + ((Small * x) + (Large * y)));
      System.out.println("Expenses = " + (Food + Facility));
      System.out.println("Difference = " + (Revenue - Expenses));

    } else
      System.out.println("The number of dogs has exceeded the facility limit.");
  }
}
}
```

Comment: That makes sense.  Because if I initialize it too early, then it will recognize it for the wrong usage.  Thank you!

Comment: just wondering, why did your code block the else part of my original code though because that's not working now?

Comment: well when you set Small equal to (8 - Large) and then change neither Small or Large again, than it will always satisfy the condition (Small + Large) <= 8, unless you initially enter a value greater than or equal to 8 for Large

Comment: @ CSCH Exactly!  Let's say I enter the number 9.  I want the else result to still display.  I am trying to fix it, but I am still a noob.

Comment: my previous statement was wrong. Its actually because in the if statement what you essentially have is (Small + Large) <= 8, and replacing the value for Small with 8 - large, we have (Small + Large) <= 8 being ((8 - Large) + Large) <= 8 which is always true

Comment: So what you want to do is print out "The number of dogs has exceeded the facility limit." whenever the input value is greater than 8?

Comment: Wow!  I never even thought about that!  That makes perfect sense!  How would you implement that though?  What would you change Small to in that case?  Because that one just threw me for a loop.  I thought I had it all figured out by writing Small down that way.

Comment: I think I got it figured out by changing the else to (Large <= 8)